# how to display wkwebview inside stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am just starting to learn Swift and I am trying to build an elementary web browser using the Interface Builder. The problem I ran into is that once I embed the WKWebView inside a stack view, it stops displaying any content (the once called stackWebView). It works as expected if the webview is outside the stack, inside the ViewController (the one called topWebView). This is the code I've written so far. I am aware there are solutions for doing this programmatically, but I'm trying to understand the interaction between the Interface Builder and the code. So how can I display content inside the stacked webview?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var urlName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topWebView: WKWebView!


    private func loadWebPage(_ s: String){
        topWebView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: s)!))
        stackWebView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: s)!))
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        urlName.text = textField.text
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        urlName.text = textField.text
        loadWebPage(urlName.text!)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        urlName.delegate = self
        let startURL = URL(string: "https://www.duckduckgo.com")
        topWebView.load(URLRequest(url: startURL!))
        stackWebView.load(URLRequest(url: startURL!))
    }

}
```

Comment: add stackiview in interface builder and arrange subview as web view in stackeview  by programmatically or combine them in interface builder using embed option

Comment: That's exactly how I did it, by embedding the web view and the text field inside the stack view. It's at that point that the web content stopped displaying (it shows just fine for the non embedded web view called stackWebView).

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code which works fine for me. Am able to load web views in stack view and even by entering url in the textfield also

**Code**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var urlName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackWebView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topWebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        urlName.delegate = self
        topWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        stackWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        let startURLString = "https://www.duckduckgo.com"
        loadWebPage(startURLString: startURLString)
    }



    private func loadWebPage(startURLString: String){
        var formattedURLString  =  startURLString
        if !formattedURLString.lowercased().contains("http") {
            formattedURLString = "http://\(formattedURLString)"
        }
        let startURL : URL = URL(string: formattedURLString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)!
        print(startURL)
        topWebView.load(URLRequest(url: startURL))
        stackWebView.load(URLRequest(url: startURL))
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        loadWebPage(startURLString: urlName.text!)
        return true
    }



    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

**Storyboard**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14113" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="StackViewExample" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dCG-SE-8O1">
                                <rect key="frame" x="32" y="52" width="311" height="30"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="30" id="YQA-bf-cZ2"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" id="81P-xI-VQI"/>
                                </connections>
                            </textField>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="10" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="naB-Di-vk8">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="114" width="375" height="553"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <wkWebView contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TzL-qx-9oE">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="271.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.36078431370000003" green="0.38823529410000002" blue="0.4039215686" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <wkWebViewConfiguration key="configuration">
                                            <audiovisualMediaTypes key="mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback" none="YES"/>
                                            <wkPreferences key="preferences"/>
                                        </wkWebViewConfiguration>
                                    </wkWebView>
                                    <wkWebView contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8Th-zS-htL">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="281.5" width="375" height="271.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.36078431370000003" green="0.38823529410000002" blue="0.4039215686" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <wkWebViewConfiguration key="configuration">
                                            <audiovisualMediaTypes key="mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback" none="YES"/>
                                            <wkPreferences key="preferences"/>
                                        </wkWebViewConfiguration>
                                    </wkWebView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="dCG-SE-8O1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" constant="32" id="6ud-iU-788"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="naB-Di-vk8" secondAttribute="bottom" id="I9W-Y2-PPp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="naB-Di-vk8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="dCG-SE-8O1" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="32" id="Muf-dU-Xgl"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="naB-Di-vk8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="X7T-e4-rEF"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="naB-Di-vk8" secondAttribute="trailing" id="iod-JL-8w5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="dCG-SE-8O1" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="32" id="oQT-3t-opj"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="dCG-SE-8O1" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="32" id="qtr-49-LHO"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="stackWebView" destination="8Th-zS-htL" id="Iie-Yi-yyB"/>
                        <outlet property="topWebView" destination="TzL-qx-9oE" id="wLl-yX-yj7"/>
                        <outlet property="urlName" destination="dCG-SE-8O1" id="jhS-ly-gdy"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Yes, but you see, the text field is not embedded within astack view together with a webview. Once you do that, your code doesn't work anymore. Must be an iOS restriction or something, I'll find another way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is must that you have four constraints to the webView. Orelse it parent should have four constraints